# Disable FakeItEasy's AutoMocking

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fakeiteasy

Say I have an interface

```
public interface IDatabase
{
  IObjectSet<Table1> Table1 {get;}

  IObjectSet<Table2> Table2 {get;}

  //goes on to around Table400
}
```

So when I create an instance with FakeItEasy:

```
var fakeDb = A.Fake<IDatabase>();
```

All the properties (tables) have a default fake value.
I can see why this is handy in most senarios but in mine, I need all of them to be `null`

Is there a clever way of doing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure it that's how it was meant to work but I found that you can set expectation on all calls to an object:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var fake = A.Fake<IDatabase>();
    fake.AnyCall().DoesNothing();

    var result = fake.Table1;

    Assert.IsNull(result);
}
```

By using *AnyCall* you can set expectation on all of the calls to a specific fake - in this case *DoesNothing* returns the default value of *null*

Comment: Beautiful! It did exacly what i needed. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

just for completeness. Another way to tell FakeItEasy it shouldn't automatically create default fake values is to declare your fake as strict like so:

```
var fake = A.Fake<IDatabase>(builder => builder.Strict());
```

though in this case FakeItEasy will throw an exception if a member is called that wasn't set up before.

In your case the suggested version is the best, though I would write it with the `A` syntax so you better see which calls are setups on fakes:

```
A.CallTo(fake).DoesNothing();
```

these two are identical.